# JMeter - non-linear VU growth during ramp up period

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, performance-testing

I have an issue with a non-linear growth of active threads number. It happens at the beginning of the test and becomes linear later. Important: it occurs during distrubuted and non-GUI mode. Have you had similar problem? Are there any JMeter parameters which can change it?

In non-distributed mode ramp-up period is fully linear. I use 1 master and 4 slaves, but it happens also for 1 master and 1 slave.

[image]